# How to apply a Scala Function to two different columns data frame Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, function, dataframe, tuples

I am currently writing a script in Scala, for this, I have pre-coded a function which looks like this:

```
def reducer_scala(node: (Int, List[Int])): (List[(Int, Int)], Int) = {
var counter = 0
var minimum = node._1
var value_List = List.empty[Int]
var joined = List.empty[(Int, Int)]

for(value <- node._2){
    if(value < minimum){
      minimum = value
    }
    value_List :+= value
  }

if(minimum<node._1){
    joined = joined :+ (node._1, minimum)
    for(value <- value_List){
  
      if(minimum != value){
        counter = counter + 1
        joined = joined :+ (value, minimum)
      }
    }
  }
  return (joined, counter)
}
```

As you see, it takes as input a tuple of an Int and a List[Int].

I would now like to apply it to two columns in my Dataframe that looks like this:

```
  _1,      collect_list(_2)

   0|             [1]|
|  1|       [2, 3, 0]|
|  3|          [4, 1]|
|  5|             [6]|
|  6|          [7, 5]|
|  2|             [1]|
|  4|             [3]|
|   7|             [6]
```

As you see, the first column is an Int and the second one is a List.

I would like to know:
-How to convert reunite each element of both columns in the same tuple
-How to apply my reducer_scala function to each element ( Tuple(element_column_1, element_column_2))

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The `select()` function enables you to apply your udf to each row of your dataframe, selecting the columns you want with `col("colname")`
You just have to tweak a little bit your function so that it takes two separate arguments instead of a tuple.

Make sure that your function is registered as udf eg:

`val reducer = udf {(x: Int, y: List[Int]) => reducer_scala(x, y)}`

And then call it with `df = df.select(reducer(col("colname1"), col("colname2")))`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Hugo ! Would you believe it if I tell you I have a friend with the exact same name as yours ?

Comment: Hello Hugo, sorry to disturb you again but there's a small problem with your solution, I get the following error when calling df.show().                                                             "Task not serializable
Caused by: NotSerializableException: $line1e89a5c742cb4cfba468fb44109b23bb252.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$TupleUDFs$"